# ASP.NET MVC3 - Redirect to a different directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config

We have a bunch of published URLs that reference a directory called "events"

```
http://www.mysite.com/anniversary/events/    
http://www.mysite.com/anniversary/events/[...]
```

They now want to rename "events" to "events1" so I need to redirect all URLs that look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/anniversary/events/[...]
```

**To:**

```
http://www.mysite.com/anniversary/events1
http://www.mysite.com/anniversary/events1/[...]
```

**I've done these in Apache - Not sure if I am on the right track?**

```
<rule name="events1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^/anniversary/events(/.+)?$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/aniverssary/events1{C:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

What should this look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that IIS has a really nice rewrite rule pattern tester. I found this [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns) extremely helpful. If you use the IIS URL Rewrite GUI, you can create a test redirect and then the URL Rewrite will write the redirect into web.config. You can then look in there and check your syntax.